# Remove Blank Rows in CSV Using Python

Tags: python, csv

I've seen some threads on this, but none seem to be simple.  I'm looking for a simple code to remove the blank rows in a CSV using python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively (to the duplicate question) you can consider using `grep`

```
grep -Pv ^,*$ input_file.csv > output_file.csv
```

e.g. any line in `input_file.csv` that is not either blank or solely composed of commas get redirected to `output_file.csv`